# Java Out of memory Exception Occurring After Scheduling PostgreSQL Stored Procedure On Heroku Server

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku-postgres

My Java application is deployed on Heroku Server and it contains one scheduled job (which is Stored Procedure of PostgreSQL).

The scheduler successfully starts the procedure execution and also logs get printed.

But, after some time the java application causes an exception

> JAVA.LANG.OUTOFMEMORYERROR java heap space

and it stops working without completion of the scheduled job.

What should I do to resolve this error?

Please Find Exception Screenshot

[image: Please Find Exception Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to tell us minor details like the SQL statement you were running, but here is my guess:

You ran a statement with a large result set, and the driver tried to snarf it all into RAM.

In that case you should use a `PreparedStatement` and use `setPrepareThreshold` to set a fetch size. Then a cursor will be used, and you avoid the problem.

See [the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/server-prepare.html) for details.

Comment: [Getting results based on a cursor](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor) also explains this - especially the part about turning autocommit off